# How is correctly called "parent" of nested loop?

Tags: terminology

I have a general question across the languages. How is correctly called the "parent" loop? The higher one:

```
for(int A=0;A<10;A++)
{
 for(int B=0;B<10;B++)
 {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would say the "outer loop" and the "inner loop".

Comment: Agree, however it gets more complicated with more nested loops. :D

Comment: With deeper nesting, usually the loop variable works: "the A loop" and "the B loop"

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about loops:

http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-nested-loop.htm